# Is there a Go version of the "MD5-based block cipher"?

Tags: php, go, md5, encryption

I would like to implement a Go application that is going to send some private data to a server. The code on server is PHP and uses a "MD5-based block cipher". The PHP encrypt/decrypt code is here:
http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/md5-based-block-cipher.htm

Is there an equivalent routine in Go?

Comment: MD5 is a hashing algorithm, not an encryption algorithm.  As such, there is no possibility of 'decrypting' the output of MD5.  The encryption in the link uses MD5 hashing to generate the IV (initialization vector) used with XOR encryption.

Comment: It is quite possible to use a strong hash function to make a strong block cipher and that is what the PHP code appears to do.  Whether it is a good idea or not is a different question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like that code is similar to the [MDC algorithm](http://web.textfiles.com/software/sfs7.txt) which is a way of making a cipher from a hash function.

There are much better ciphers that that though - have a look in [Go's crypto library](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/).

If you are desperate to interoperate with that particular PHP code then you'll have to convert it to Go yourself I think, but if I had a choice I would choose a better cipher (something using AES).